# How to view powerpoint in web?

Tags: java, html, powerpoint

Is it possible to view powerpoint in my website without converting it to PDF (just like what google drive does to powerpoint files uploaded).
I want to view pptx with animation, so I don't want it to convert to PDF/HTML to retain the animation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please read how to ask a question. Questions need to be about specific issues - post some code, at least show you've had a go.  Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.yourwebsite.com/powerpoint.pptx&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here is the link of [tutorial](http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/embed-powerpoint-web-html-or-flash/)

Comment: thanks.. is there a way for this to work on local files.. I tried this and i only managed to view powerpoint files that are available online

Comment: Thats because, google does not have an access to the files on your local machine. You will have to upload it.